# Assigning the value in the variable from the FOR loop in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have written one batch script, to get the all pdf files in the directory including Subfolders, but i want to know is it possible to assign the value of `%%x` in the some other variable, like `set temp = %%~na`.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

setlocal
for /r %%a in (*.pdf) do (
   echo %%~na
)
endlocal
```

Comment: You just did it in the example above your code, despite that using the special variables like `temp` or `tmp` is discouraged because it is being used by other programs to find the path to user's temporary folder, but this is the way, you just need put the assignment inside the loop. BUT surely you don't want to assign the value of `%%x` to a variable for sake of doing an assignment, So explain the reason for the assignment, what are trying to achieve with that assignment, and more importantly what did you do to achieve the goal what problems did face in doing so.

Comment: Another point: Don't use spaces around the equal sign in the assignment, batch is different from other languages/scripts that you may have worked with, in batch/cmd those extra spaces will become part of the variable/value. and as a best practice always try to put the whole assignment between quotes. Something like this: `set "MyVar=Value"`

Answer (score 1):

Almost exactly as you had it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R %%a in (*.pdf) do (
   set "var=%%~na"
   echo !var!
)
```

You do not have to `endlocal` as it will end when the script completes in this case.

Doing `setlocal` a second time is an issue. You did `setlocal` at the beginning when you enabled `delayedexpansion` but that being said, you never used it. Look at `setlocal /?` you will notice `!` is used instead of `%` in order to tell the system which variables should be used in the delayed environment expansion.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the above, once the loop has completed will only hold the value of the last `.pdf` in the variable, `%var%`. Also, because the value used the `%%~na` modifier, and you are running a `R`ecursive `for` loop, the value held will only provide the name of the `.pdf` file without its `d`rive, `p`ath or e`x`tension. _This would mean that you don't really have any idea of where that file is in relation to the current working directory._ Enter `For /?` at the Command Prompt for the other modifiers information if you want something different.